# Pre-Calc - find the height of triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I need help on a problem. I'm lost and I don't know what to do. Could anyone give me some pointers in the right direction? My problem is below:

[image]

*edit* - Even though it says test on the top, it isn't. It's homework that isn't due for another week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve for $CE$ using 
$$\tan 7.9 =\frac{BC}{CE}=\frac{160}{CE}$$

and solve for $DC$ using

$$\tan 68.9=\frac{DC}{CE}$$
and adding $BC+DC$ will give the desired answer.

Comment: So CE would be 160 * tan (7.9) = 22.20                                and DC would be 22.20 * tan (68.9) = 57.53                       and then BC + DC would be 57.53 + 160 = 217.53?

Comment: No, check your algebra. $\tan 7.9=\frac{160}{CE}\Rightarrow CE=\frac{160}{\tan 7.9}$

Comment: CE = 160 / tan (7.9) = 1153.05                                   and DC would be 1153.05 * tan (68.9) = 2988.19..                 then BC + DC would be 160 + 2988.19 = 3148.19 - thanks for taking your time out to help. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Using right triangle(BCE), calculate BE

BE = 160/sin(7.9)

angle CDE =(90-68.9) = 21.1

angle DEB =68.9 + 7.9 =76.8

use law of sins(for triangle BED)

BD/sin(DEB) = BE/sin(CDE)

BD = BE *sin(DEB)/sin(CDE)

BD = (160/sin(7.9) )*sin(76.8) /sin(21.1)

BD = [160*sin(76.8)]/[sin(7.9) * sin(21.1)]

BD = 3148.21928986

BD(rounded to nearest integer) =3148